# Error handler parameter type for express server?

Tags: typescript, express

I'm migrating my express server to Typescript.
See below a minimum example.

My problem is the type to assign to the argument of the error handler `handleServerErrors`.

if I define it as `Error`, tsc complains that `error.code` is not part of Error. So I resorted to `any` just to continue.
Seems tsc is taking the js definition of Error, not the nodejs one.
And yes, I have installed `@types/node`

```
import express = require("express");

const handleServerErrors = (error: any) => {
    if(error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
        console.log("\nServer already running.\n");
    }
    else {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
};


const app = express();
app
    .listen(4400, () => console.log("Running")
    .once("error", handleServerErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above change 3rd line to:
`const handleServerErrors = (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => {`

Not obvious to find out.